# Installing Openpyxl for preinstalled python 2.7 mac lion

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I would like to install openpyxl-1.8.4 on Python 2.7 that comes with Mac Lion. My Python compiler is under system/library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions/2.7/bin.
I tried

> python2.7 setup.py install

and also

> sudo python2.7 setup.py install

and seems to me none of them works. Am I missing something? I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please supply some more information here, what is the error message. When you type python2.7 does python start? Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Answer (score 3):

Install openpyxl using pip: `sudo pip install openpyxl`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps :

1. Download the latest version of `Openpyxl` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl)
2. Extract the downloaded file (`openpyxl-x.x.tar.gz`)
3. Open the `Terminal` and navigate to the extracted folder ( typically `\downloads\openpyxl-x.xx\` )
4. Run the following command in the Terminal :

   > > python setup.py install
5. If you have the correct permissions set on the **/Library/Python/x.x/site-packages** folder, it should run a bunch of command automatically and installation should complete without any issues. If not, you would need `read-write` permissions on just **site-packages** folder. If you come across any other error, the terminal command would prompt regarding that.

Comment: Then I got error: Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for et-xmlfile
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('et-xmlfile'). I give up U______U